# Swagger ignoring controller route path for one action

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger

I have a little problem with Swagger: I created a new action in my controller but when starting the web server I notice Swagger completely ignores the route of the controller. Instead of having "api/users/login" route, I just have "/login".

[Screen from my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTgLF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specified the route as

```
[HttpPost("/login")]
```

It should be

```
[HttpPost("login")]
```

When you start the path with a slash, you override the parent route.

You can check my deep dive article for attribute routing for more info: https://joonasw.net/view/attribute-routing-cheat-sheet-for-aspnet-core